# Signer appears twice using compositeTemplates

Tags: docusignapi

We've been sending compositeTemplates via the API for a while but hit a new issue recently when we started using a new template. Here's the compositeTemplates part of the request:

```
[
    {
        "compositeTemplateId"=>"1",
        "serverTemplates"=>[
            {
                "sequence"=>"1",
                "templateId"=>"4f01d07d-9362-4651-8bef-dccc5dbef03c"
            }
        ],
        "document"=>{
            "name"=>"test1.pdf",
            "documentId"=>"1"
        },
        "inlineTemplates"=>[
            {
                "sequence"=>"1",
                "recipients"=>{
                    "signers"=>[
                        {
                            : name=>"Test Test",
                            : first_name=>"test",
                            : email=>"test@test.com",
                            : roleName=>"Client",
                            : clientUserId=>1,
                            : recipientId=>1,
                            : routingOrder=>1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "compositeTemplateId"=>"2",
        "serverTemplates"=>[
            {
                "sequence"=>"2",
                "templateId"=>"0F0DA764-3A4D-42EF-BC0E-1386487971C7"
            }
        ],
        "document"=>{
            "name"=>"test2.pdf",
            "documentId"=>"1"
        },
        "inlineTemplates"=>[
            {
                "sequence"=>"2",
                "recipients"=>{
                    "signers"=>[
                        {
                            : name=>"Test Test",
                            : first_name=>"test",
                            : email=>"test@test.com",
                            : roleName=>"Client",
                            : clientUserId=>1,
                            : recipientId=>1,
                            : routingOrder=>1
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The resulting envelope has the recipient tag twice, one for each template:

```
Recipient Test Test (test@test.com) | Client at route Signer 1
Recipient () | Client at route Signer 10
```

Both templates have the signer at RoutingOrder 10 and RecipientID 2. I have tried different combinations of recipientId and routingOrder but nothing works. Also, I can't modify these templates.

Comment: Why can't you modify the templates?  Also, have you tried downloading the XML definitions of the templates and doing a diff to see if any differences exist?  If it still works with the old template then the issue is not in the platform but rather specific to your templates or code that uses them.

Comment: The template is shared with many people and I don't own it. I've looked at this template vs other templates we've successfully worked with and they look pretty similar. All have first signer at RoutingOrder 10.